# Resize & scale an image in PHP

Tags: php, image

I'm currently building an image uploading script which has some basic editing features in using a combination of PHP & jQuery, I think the problem is in my PHP calculations. The bit that I'm stuck on is scaling up and image.

Currently they upload an image and on the next screen that image is displayed with a target box, the idea being that they resize the image and move it around so only what is displayed within the target box will be what's saved when they continue.

When the click the save button the jQuery posts the dimensions, offset().top & offset().left of the target box & image then the PHP resizes & crops the image based on that.

Now here's the bit I'm stuck on the end result that's output will be an image that's 800 x 600 but the target box they are using and the initial size of the image they get to resize & move around is 640 x 480. The reason for what they see being smaller is so it fits better on their displays while resizing & moving the images.

How do I accommodate the difference between the size that they see and work with (640 x 480) and what the actual output size will be (800 x 600). This has really killed my brain, I've got it all working if I make the target area the user sees 800 x 600 but not when it's 640 x 480.

Keep in mind when the user resizes the image in the browser they could make it bigger than 800 x 600 but of course only a size of 640 x 480 would be within the target box. I'm not certain that makes a difference but I think it will.

This has really hurt my brain so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Divide by `0.8` or multiply `1.25` depending on which direction you're going? Let them select an area in the 640x480 box and then multiply the picked values by `1.25` to scale them to the 800x600 target.

Comment: So if the image they are scaling up is larger than the target box I should multiple the width & height of the image by by 1.25? Just checking  that I'm clear on this.

Thanks for the quick comment too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment left by @Cobra_Fast helped me a lot in getting this to work. I basically had to multiple the image size by 1.25 & the start location for the crop (so that it moved to the correct position now the image was larger).

Thank you very much.